# Django div reload - ajax GET after POST does not get latest database model instances

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

In a chat-like app, I'm using ajax calls to POST a new message and update the messages displayed on the page without reloading the entire page. My ajax call for posting works - a new message instance is created in the database. However, afterwards when I make an ajax call to GET all messages, the new message is missing from the resulting query set. If I refresh the page fully, I can see all the messages, but that's not what I'm after.

**HTML messages template:**

```
    {% for message in messages %}
    <p>
        {{ message.content }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

**HTML chat template:**

```
<div id="chat">
    {% include "messages.html" %}
</div>

<form id="post-message-form", method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    [my form goes here]
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#post-message-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    var data = new FormData($form.get(0));

    $.ajax({
        url: '/post/a/new/message/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: refresh_chat,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })

    return false;
}

function refresh_chat(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get/all/messages/,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(json) {
            $('#chat').html(json['data']);
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

**Views:**

```
import json
from django.template import loader
from .forms import MessageForm

# /post/a/new/message/
def post_message(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.save()
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({'status': 1,
                            'message': 'Message posted!'}),
                content_type='application/json'
            )

# /get/all/messages/
def get_messages(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        messages = loader.render_to_string('messages.html', context={'messages': Message.objects.all(), 'form': MessageForm()})
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({'data': messages}),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
```

Any ideas why I do not get the latest database data when I call an ajax GET after POST? Thanks!

Comment: `success: refresh_div` - should this be `refresh_chat`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was a typo. It's not what's causing my problem though.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQLite, default Django app setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if I do my chat refresh on the ajax "done" call instead of on "success" it works:

```
$('#post-message-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    var data = new FormData($form.get(0));

    $.ajax({
        url: '/post/a/new/message/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function() {
        refresh_chat();
    });

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for commenting!